# PHP Gmail API throws error 403 while composing

Tags: php, gmail-api

I have authenticated a google user and code the auth token. With this token I'm trying to compose an email but I receive an error.

```
Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send: (403) Insufficient Permission
```

Here is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose");
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
```

Having setup the credentials and after successful oauth,

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken() && isset($_POST['message'])) {

$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

// Prepare the message in message/rfc822
try {

    // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($_POST["message"]), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $msg->setRaw($mime);
    $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);

 } catch (Exception $e) {
    print($e->getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: Please, include the relevant fragments of code in your question instead of linking to external resources (i.e. pastie.org).

Comment: Did you enable gmail api in the developer console?Also try you request(same information you provided in the code) in the google API explorer..Here is the link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send